# How to prevent Lua from returning the final value of an expression?

Tags: lua

This is a weird question as I'm not so sure how to ask, but here's the problem:

```
BeforeTime = os.clock()

function NewFunction( Name, Value )
         Name = function()
            return Value
         end
end

NewFunction( RunningTime, (os.clock()-BeforeTime) )

while true do
  print(RunningTime()) -- will always return same value, i want the updated
end
```

The example above is not exactly my context, but its the easiest way to explain my problem.

I guess I could require that the parameter 'Value' needs to be a function, but is there another way?

Comment: I think you're confusing `os.clock` and `os.time`.

Comment: @hjpotter92 i only used os.clock here because i wanted something that updated its value, but thats not the context on my actual code

Answer (score 1):

`NewFunction` creates a function and assigns it to the Name parameter. But, in Lua, actual parameters are passed [by value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_by_value#Call_by_value) (like Java and C) and formal parameters are effectively local variables. The assigned value is never used and it can't be used outside the function.

To make a function return a non-empty list of values, use a `return` statement.

Here's a similar function for a timer:

```
local function CreateTimer()
    local BeforeTime = os.clock()
    return function() 
        return os.clock() - BeforeTime  
    end
end
```

You can use it like this:

```
local RunningTime = CreateTimer()

while true do
    print(RunningTime())
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not run because `NewFunction` doesn't do what you think it should.

If you add the line below before the loop, then it works fine.

`RunningTime = function() return (os.clock()-BeforeTime) end`